# Is it okay to assign java parameters to JAVA_OPTS without space in between?

Tags: jboss

Is it okay to assign java parameters to JAVA_OPTS without space in between ?

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS  -Xloggc:/opt/tmp/gc.log-XX:+PrintGCDetails-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space must be present in between `JAVA_OPTS` else you would get `Error: A fatal exception has occurred. The program will exit.` error while starting the server with standalone.sh/domain.sh file.